# Check for camel case in Python

Tags: python, regex, camelcasing

I would like to check if a string is a camel case or not (boolean). I am inclined to use a regex but any other elegant solution would work. I wrote a simple regex

```
(?:[A-Z])(?:[a-z])+(?:[A-Z])(?:[a-z])+
```

Would this be correct? Or am I missing something?

**Edit**

I would like to capture names in a collection of text documents of the format

```
McDowell
O'Connor
T.Kasting
```

**Edit2**

I have modified my regex based on the suggestion in the comments

```
(?:[A-Z])(?:\S?)+(?:[A-Z])(?:[a-z])+
```

Comment: It's kind of a difficult thing to determine programatically.  Is `camel` camel case?  What about `_camel`, `Camel`, `_Camel`, `CONSTCAMEL`, `HTML`, or `var_camelCase`?  It's pretty difficult to define unless you know ahead of time what the formatting is.

Comment: @DavidNehme Not really, I have checked it and my requirements are different/

Comment: @sr2222 What do you mean by formatting? I am looking to capture names like McGauge, LePierre etc in a piece of text. Hope this adds more context.

Comment: @mcenley, then specify your requirements?

Comment: @mcenley What about O'Connor?

Comment: @Qtax The regex on the link doesn't deal with a boolean function of CamelCase capture but rather a replace of CamelCase to camel_case. I may be wrong here if I didn't understand the question on the dup link correctly.

Comment: @agf Yes, I would like to capture those as well. Also something like "T.Mildred"

Comment: So this has less to do with CamelCase and more to do with identifying proper names?

Comment: @sr2222 Ah, yes. The assumption being checking for camel case (along with other "features") would help my task.

Comment: So what's wrong with taking any token that starts with a capital letter and contains n other characters?  The only real trick there is avoiding other proper nouns and words at the beginning of sentences that aren't names.

Comment: One would capture strings like 'The','Article' etc. Checking for camel cased names would provide better insights.

Comment: But a name like Bill Williams will get by your filter... in any case, what about any token starting with a capital and containing a second capital that is non-contiguous to the first?

Comment: @sr2222 Yup, you've hit the nail. Is the regex correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10141/discussion-between-mcenley-and-sr2222)

Comment: How about some examples of inputs you would like to fail?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could check if a string has both upper and lowercase.

```
def is_camel_case(s):
    return s != s.lower() and s != s.upper() and "_" not in s


tests = [
    "camel",
    "camelCase",
    "CamelCase",
    "CAMELCASE",
    "camelcase",
    "Camelcase",
    "Case",
    "camel_case",
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, is_camel_case(test))
```

Output:

```
camel False
camelCase True
CamelCase True
CAMELCASE False
camelcase False
Camelcase True
Case True
camel_case False
```

Comment: Surely this doesn't work? CAMELcase is not valid and will return true.

Comment: It depends if you want to allow acronyms. e.g. `DecodeRGB` or `DecodeRgb`

Comment: This returns false for `_camelCase`

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This is not correct

Comment: Also does not handle numeric or punctuation well.

Comment: Should there also be a check for `.isalnum()`? And also a check that string does not start with a number?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something more like:

```
(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)+
```

Altho that would allow all caps. You could avoid that with:

```
(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+
```

Anchor the expression with `^` and `$` or `\z` if required.

Answer (score 3):

if you do not want strings starting with upper-case e.g `Case` and `Camelcase` to pass `True`.  edit @william's answer:

```
def is_camel_case(s):
  if s != s.lower() and s != s.upper() and "_" not in s and sum(i.isupper() for i in s[1:-1]) == 1:
      return True
  return False



tests = [
"camel",
"camelCase",
"CamelCase",
"CAMELCASE",
"camelcase",
"Camelcase",
"Case",
"camel_case",
]

for test in tests:
   print(test, is_camel_case(test))
```

the results:

```
camel False
camelCase True
CamelCase True
CAMELCASE False
camelcase False
Camelcase False
Case False
camel_case False
```

Comment: "CAMELCASE", "Camelcase", and "Case" are valid CamelCase strings.

Comment: @MattS The question is if that is useful. In many coding styles, 'Case' would be a simple class name, and not a camelcase class or method name. Camel case is useful to distinguish words in a string. 'Camelcase' is also not a very useful identifier. Coming from a google search, Cidis answer is the one that helped me the most.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your string to camel case using a library like [`inflection`](https://inflection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inflection.camelize). If it doesn't change, it must've already been camel case.

```
from inflection import camelize

def is_camel_case(s):
    # return True for both 'CamelCase' and 'camelCase'
    return camelize(s) == s or camelize(s, False) == s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get away with just checking that the string has a capital with a lower case letter before it if(line =~ m/[a-z][A-Z]/). Just checking lower and upper fails on the given examples. ~Ben

Comment: I have modified my regex in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_string= 'hiSantyWhereAreYou'  `Change the string here and try`
index=[x for x,y in enumerate(list(sub_string)) if(y.isupper())] `Finding the index 
of caps`
camel_=[]
temp=0
for m in index:
    camel_.append(sub_string[temp:m])
    temp=m
if(len(index)>0):
    camel_.append(sub_string[index[-1]::])
    print('The individual camel case words are', camel_) `Output is in list`
else:
    camel_.append(sub_string)
    print('The given string is not camel Case')
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation about *how* and *why* your code snippet provides an answer to the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This regex solution worked for my use case `([A-Z][a-z\S]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)`

Answer (score 0):

[**CamelCase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

> is the practice of writing phrases without spaces or punctuation,
> **indicating the separation of words with a *single* capitalized letter**

```
def iscamelcase(string):
    non_alpha = [i for i in string if not i.isalpha()]
    substrings= string.translate({ord(i): ' ' for i in non_alpha}).split(' ')
    for string in substrings:
        if not all(char.isupper() for char in string):
            for idx,i in enumerate(string):
                if i.isupper() and idx > 0:
                    return True
    return False
```

1. search the string for other signs than charackters and store in
   `non_alpha`
2. *replace* all non_alpha signs with empty space and split them by empty space to create `substrings`
3. Check all substrings to be not fully uppercase and if not the index
   of the uppercase cant be >0

**Output**

```
camel False
camelCase True
CamelCase True
CAMELCASE False
camelcase False
Camelcase False
Case False
camel_case False
```